# Passing data to SMOTE after applying train/test split

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataframe, smote

I'm trying to resample my dataset after splitting it into train and test partitions using SMOTE. Here's my code:

```
smote_X = df[cols]
smote_Y = df[target_col]

#Split train and test data
smote_train_X,smote_test_X,smote_train_Y,smote_test_Y = train_test_split(smote_X,smote_Y,test_size = .25,random_state = 111)

smote_train_Y_series = smote_train_Y.iloc[:,0]

#oversampling minority class using smote
os = SMOTE(random_state = 0)
os_smote_X,os_smote_Y = os.fit_sample(smote_train_X,smote_train_Y_series)
```

I added line #5 to convert the DataFrame coming out of `train_test_split` to Series as the newer version of SMOTE `fit_sample` ([docs](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html#imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.fit_sample)) wants this data type but it now throws the following error.

Any ideas how to fix it?

> -------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        16 #oversampling minority class using smote
>        17 os = SMOTE(random_state = 0)
>   ---> 18 os_smote_X,os_smote_Y = os.fit_sample(smote_train_X,smote_train_Y_series)
>        19 os_smote_X = pd.DataFrame(data = os_smote_X,columns=cols)
>        20 os_smote_Y = pd.DataFrame(data = os_smote_Y,columns=target_col)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/base.py in
>   fit_resample(self, X, y)
>        86         if self._X_columns is not None:
>        87             X_ = pd.DataFrame(output[0], columns=self._X_columns)
>   ---> 88             X_ = X_.astype(self._X_dtypes)
>        89         else:
>        90             X_ = output[0]
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
>   astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)    5863
>   results.append(    5864                         col.astype(
>   -> 5865                             dtype=dtype[col_name], copy=copy, errors=errors, **kwargs    5866                         )    5867
>   )
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
>   astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)    5846                 if
>   len(dtype) > 1 or self.name not in dtype:    5847
>   raise KeyError(
>   -> 5848                         "Only the Series name can be used for "    5849                         "the key in Series dtype mappings." 
>   5850                     )
>
> KeyError: 'Only the Series name can be used for the key in Series
>   dtype mappings.'

**Upd 1/28/2020:**
Tried two more options with no luck so far. **Still looking for help.**

A. Passing the raw outputs of `train_test_split`:

```
#oversampling minority class using smote
os = SMOTE(random_state = 0)
os_smote_X,os_smote_Y = os.fit_sample(smote_train_X,smote_train_Y)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 #oversampling minority class using smote
>         2 os = SMOTE(random_state = 0)
>   ----> 3 os_smote_X,os_smote_Y = os.fit_resample(smote_train_X,smote_train_Y)
>         4 os_smote_X = pd.DataFrame(data = os_smote_X,columns=cols)
>         5 os_smote_Y = pd.DataFrame(data = os_smote_Y,columns=target_col)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/base.py in
>   fit_resample(self, X, y)
>        73         """
>        74         check_classification_targets(y)
>   ---> 75         X, y, binarize_y = self._check_X_y(X, y)
>        76 
>        77         self.sampling_strategy_ = check_sampling_strategy(
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/base.py in
>   _check_X_y(self, X, y, accept_sparse)
>       148         if hasattr(y, "loc"):
>       149             # store information to build a series
>   --> 150             self._y_name = y.name
>       151             self._y_dtype = y.dtype
>       152         else:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
>   **getattr**(self, name)    5177             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):    5178
>   return self[name]
>   -> 5179             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)    5180     5181     def **setattr**(self, name, value):
>
> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

B. Converting `smote_train_X` to matrix before passing it alongside `smote_train_Y` being converted to Series:

```
smote_train_X_matrix = smote_train_X.as_matrix()
smote_train_Y_series = smote_train_Y.iloc[:,0]

#oversampling minority class using smote
os = SMOTE(random_state = 0)
os_smote_X,os_smote_Y = os.fit_resample(smote_train_X_matrix,smote_train_Y_series)
```

**Note** that the resulting matrix and series show a shape of (4633, 46) and (4633,) respectively.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py
>   in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)    1677
>   blocks = [
>   -> 1678                     make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))    1679                 ]
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py
>   in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype, fastpath)    3283
>
> -> 3284     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)    3285
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py
>   in **init**(self, values, placement, ndim)
>       127                 "Wrong number of items passed {val}, placement implies "
>   --> 128                 "{mgr}".format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs))
>       129             )
>
> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 46, placement implies 44
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         2 os = SMOTE(random_state = 0)
>         3 os_smote_X,os_smote_Y = os.fit_resample(smote_train_X_matrix,smote_train_Y_series)
>   ----> 4 os_smote_X = pd.DataFrame(data = os_smote_X,columns=cols)
>         5 os_smote_Y = pd.DataFrame(data = os_smote_Y,columns=target_col)
>         6 ###
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in
>   **init**(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
>       438                 mgr = init_dict({data.name: data}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>       439             else:
>   --> 440                 mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
>       441 
>       442         # For data is list-like, or Iterable (will consume into list)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py
>   in init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
>       211         block_values = [values]
>       212 
>   --> 213     return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
>       214 
>       215
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py
>   in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)    1686
>   blocks = [getattr(b, "values", b) for b in blocks]    1687
>   tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
>   -> 1688         construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)    1689     1690
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py
>   in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)    1717
>   raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")    1718 
>   raise ValueError(
>   -> 1719         "Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(passed, implied)    1720     )    1721
>
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8410, 46), indices imply (8410,
>   44)

Comment: This is an SF topic where I found the suggested way to convert the 2nd argument of `fit_sample` to Series https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453238/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-name-when-using-smote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `smote_train_Y` is already a series, so need to use `iloc[:,0]`. Just use that in `fit_sample` function-

```
#oversampling minority class using smote
os = SMOTE(random_state = 0)
os_smote_X,os_smote_Y = os.fit_sample(smote_train_X_matrix, smote_train_Y)
```

Comment: Hi @ankit-seth, Thanks for jumping in!

If I skip the `iloc` part, I'm getting another error from SMOTE.   

>AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem - my initial dataset contained duplicate columns created after one-hot encoding of my categorical variables. The original code worked for me upon cleaning the dataset.

**Bottom line:** Make sure your dataset is sound and convert DataFrame to Series for the 2nd variable you pass to `fit_sample` of SMOTE.